# iPhone- How to set Portrait/Landscape image in Round Shaped button's imageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have to set image in circular button, Image can be picked from gallery or captured by camera.

Now when i tried to set portrait or Landscape image on my `button.imagview` with `AspectFit` Content Mode then image is not covering the whole circular button.

```
  [btnUserPic setImage:userImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  btnUserPic.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

btnUSerPic is the `UIButton` Object.

It's appearing like this-

Portrait image-

[image]

Landscape image-

[image]

If I tried to set `ConentMode`,  `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` or `UIViewContentModeCenter`  then it works to fill circle but sometimes image get distorted.

How to set image on button imageView to fill full circle of it?

Comment: You should go with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, and image is distorted because its height is smaller than image views height or the same case with width.

Comment: In my case ImageView has small height, but still image is getting distorted if i go with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It should be `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` just like you said, however, maybe the picker that picks\captures the image has something wrong on it, make sure you use a framework to do so.
- Try setting the other `UIControlStates` with the same image, that could be the problem.

Hope I added something.